# Can not run component Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api2, components

I have set up new project in web api2 and as a framework, I want to use angular2. I configured project and add there quick start Angular.

After running Home Page I saw what was expected. When I added new component and called it instead of `app.component`, I got a few errors in console. I looked up how to resolve my problem but nothing helped me.

This is the error which I get in console
[image: error]

I have now idea what is wrong in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share your code as a snippet:

1. The app module file.
2. The app component's markup and ts file.
3. The home page component's markup and ts file.

A few possible mistakes - from first glance:

1. Did you write a selector of 'my-app' in the html file of the app component instead a selector of 'home-page'?
2. It seems that you bootstrap 2 components in your app, please choose the relevant component: appComponent OR home page component in your bootstrap array.

Comment: You are right! When I removed appComponent from bootstrap array, HomePage component call without any errors. So how is it correct? Now I can have just one component that I can call in module?

Comment: declarations  array : You can have as many components in a module as you wish as long you declare them here.

bootstrap array:  you specify your entry point component. Usually its the app.component.
I suggest that you keep this component as your entry point and if you want to add more components like your home page component.

If you want the new components to be part of a new module declare them in that module. no need to add a bootstrap array there. just export those components in the sub modules and import them in the app module or any other module that uses them in its template.

Comment: Okey but how I can store that components in array. I have `bootstrap: [...]` and what should I do with it?

Comment: I'll try to give e more comprehensive explanation:
You write your components in a separate ts file.  if you want to encapsulate those components under a specific module - you need to declare them under the 'declarations' array. this is how you tell angular's compiler that they should be bundled up as part of this module. Plus, you also need to tell angular which component is the entry point of the app. For the sake of simplicity , you usually write the app component there and thats it. I hope it answered your question.

Comment: I understand but it means that I can call only one component wchich is included in bootstrap array?

Comment: You can use as many components as you want. you need to specify those components in a template - try to write your home page component inside the app component.

Comment: HomePage component is only for one view. For other views I must add new modules and there include components?

Comment: No, you don't.
For simplicity - keep all in the same app module. 
If you want to use other views - you need to add routing:
https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I dont want to use angular routing. I have controllers from webapi. Is it other option?

Comment: Yes, you can create a parent template - lets say in the home page.
And there you can write a simple navigation bar with a simple list that changes the view state.
I suggest that you close this question (the root problem was solved), and open a new one  (attach the link here) and i'll add a code snippet for you there.

Comment: I understand now. I will add it soon. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637430/connect-angular-routing-with-mvc-routing there is my new questions and problems

Answer (score 0):

The error showed in the log, says that angular could not recognize the tag. Probably you have mistaken to write in html the component tag name.

If the tag is correct, check if it is declared in the module.

Comment: I checked one hunderd times `@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HomePage],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, HomePage]
})` call: `<home-page></home-page>` and declaration: `    selector: 'home-page',
`

Comment: In the console log it was written 'my-app' is not recognized.

Comment: I know but I don t call it anywhere

Comment: Yes. Nothing change.

Comment: Can you check whether the selector name in the app.component.ts is same as the   selector used in index.html?

Comment: I call `<home-page></home-page>` in `app.component`. This work but I still can't run it alone. When I try it I have now error: https://imgur.com/a/8oRgeFD

Comment: I haven't got index.html just index.cshtml. I checed and I don't call it anywhere.

Comment: No, I mean, in the component declaration section of app.component.ts, there will be a selector, that will be associated with index.html. both need to be same.
can you make sure you have one selector in app.component.ts and that you used in index.html.

Comment: I haven't got index.html and I have only one selector in app.component.ts