# Connect Angular routing with MVC routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api2, angular2-routing

In my new project in `WebApi2` I use Angular2 framework. After configuring and adding angular I tried to call first compnent. And there is my question. How to connect angular routing with webapi2? I add new class where I add routing:
I call `<home-page>` in MVC controller view `Index.cshtml`

**app.routing.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomePage },
    { path: 'test', component: AppComponent}
];
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.template.html',
})
```

**HomePage.component.ts**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'home-page',
   templateUrl: './HomePage.template.html',
   providers: [GetContent]
})
```

**system.config.js**

```
paths: {
  // paths serve as alias
  'npm:': 'node_modules/'
},
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
  // our app is within the Angular folder
  'app': 'Angular',
  // angular bundles ...
}

meta: {
      './*.js': {
        loader: '/systemjs-angular-loader.js'
      }
}
```

**shared _Layout.cshtml**

```
<script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('Angular/main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
```

I included it to `app.module.ts` to imports section. When I launch application I see information from my `HomePage` component but when I add route path `/test`, it redirects me to `HomePage` component. Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: Can you add the html file of 'HomePage' and of 'AppComponent'?

Comment: AppComponent: `<section class="">
    <section>
        <h2>Test</h2>
    </section>
</section>` HomeComponent: `<section><h1>Home</h1></section>`

Comment: 1.do you have any errors in console? 
2. can you add your module code?

Comment: No, I haven't. `@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, routing],
    declarations: [HomePage, AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [ HomePage ]
})
export class AppModule { }` I call `<home-page></home-page>` in Index.cshtml

Comment: what is the code for your routing module? Do you export it ?

Comment: exactly this `export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomePage },
    { path: 'test', component: AppComponent}
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try edit your app.module into this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
 { path: 'home', component: HomePageComponent },
 { path: 'test', component: AppComponent}
  {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,HomePageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers : [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: error in console: `Unhandled Promise rejection: StaticInjectorError[ApplicationRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError[ApplicationRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ApplicationRef! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: StaticInjectorError[ApplicationRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError[ApplicationRef]: `

Comment: Edited - try again?

Comment: Still that same. If I navigate to /test i am redirect to home. May I have error in configuration? Or it is not possible?

Comment: The configuration of the routing i wrote above should work. I think the problem is in another place - can you add all you project files as a snippet?

Comment: I will do it but after some time. Now, I havne't got access to my computer

Comment: At first, I call my `<home-page>` component in `Index.cshtml`. My `main.ts` `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);`, `app.component`: `selector: 'my-app',  templateUrl: './app.template.html',}) export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular 2'; }`, and `HomePageComponent`: `@Component({
    selector: 'home-page',
    templateUrl: './HomePage.template.html',
    providers: [GetContent]
})`.

Comment: There are config files: system.config.js: `loader: '/systemjs-angular-loader.js'`, `'app': 'Angular',` and `script` section in shared _Layout: `System.import('Angular/main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
`

Comment: Can you add it as a snippet? (edit your question). It is hard to follow.

Comment: Can you add also the module file?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved problem. I called `<home-page>` in Index.cshtml and that view was rendered from _Layout.cshtml. When I moved called component to _Layout.cshtml all things go correct. Thanks for help!